# Exception handling in Python asyncio code

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am running the following example:

```py
import asyncio


async def longwait(n):
    print('doing long wait')
    await asyncio.sleep(n)


async def main():
    long_task = asyncio.create_task(longwait(10))
    try:
        result = await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.shield(long_task), timeout=1)  # line 'a'
        print(result)
    except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError:
        print('Taking longer than usual. Please wait.')
        result = await long_task  # line 'b'
        print(result)


asyncio.run(main())

# why not use the `result` from try block?
# maybe coz we tried to print result before it was assigned any value in try block?
```

What I don't get is why we are writing line 'b' when we already have line 'a' where we are assigning a value to the `result` variable. We can directly use the `result` from `try` clause, no?

My reasoning is that if `TimeoutError` exception is raised before the future in line 'a' is completed, it is immediately handled in the `except` clause. The `except` clause will try to print `result`. If we don't use line 'b' and since no value was assigned to `result` in the `try` clause, the `except` clause will raise `UnboundLocalError`. Is this correct reasoning? Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: This isn't anything specific to asyncio - pretty much everything relevant is the same in synchronous code.

Comment: The thing is, in above code, `try` clause wasn't actually unsuccessful per se. It just didn't finish within stipulated time frame. So my question is about the fate/result of `try` clause *after* it raises an exception which we handle in `except` clause. In above case, what happens to `result` variable in `try` clause after an exception is raised.

Comment: If line a raises an error, then the result of the computation is not defined so you should not rely on it (or wait again on the task) in the exception block. you should schedule another task or handle the exception differently in case an exception is raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] we already have line 'a' where we are assigning a value to the `result` variable.

Not really. To be more precise, we are doing *multiple* things in line *a* in that order:

1. First, we are calling `asyncio.shield(long_task)`, which returns a new `Future` (let's name it *f*).
2. Next, we are calling `asyncio.wait_for` with *f*, which returns a new coroutine object (let's name it *c*).
3. Then, we are `await`ing *c*, which returns whatever the underlying function `wait_for` returns. (Which in this case is what `shield` would return, which in turn is just what `long_task` returns.)
4. Lastly, we assign that return value from step 3 to the name `result` (which happens to be local to the `main` function).

As is the case with any combination of Python expressions/assignments, if any  preceding operation raises an exception, the interpreter **does not proceed** with the following operations. The `try`-`except`-construct allows us to define what happens *after* that. But it does not change the fact that everything starting from the line that caused the exception up until our `except`-block is completely disregarded.

> [...] `TimeoutError` exception is raised before the future in line 'a' is completed

Yes, but you need to be specific about *which* future you are talking about. In this case `wait_for` *does* in fact complete (with the exception). And before raising it cancels future *f* (returned by `shield`), but `long_task` (having been shielded from cancellation) is *not done* at this point.

In this concrete example, during **step 3** the `TimeoutError` exception is raised. This means that whatever comes after that, i.e. the variable assignment in step 4 is **not executed**.

> [...] since no value was assigned to `result` in the `try` clause, the `except` clause will raise `UnboundLocalError`.

Exactly. At runtime, the `result` name is never created in the `try`-block.

And this is what I think @user2357112 meant by everything relevant being the same with synchronous code.

It is just that in this case you may get confused by the nested futures because `long_task` is still running despite the exception having been raised. Nothing cancelled it, so in our `except`-block we can treat it the same as before. Thus we can for example await it directly (as you did) and assign its output to `result`. This is something we could *not* do in synchronous code of course.

---

### PS

Regarding your follow-up question, yes, `long_task` is still the same task. Its execution began earlier, when you called `create_task` and it remained unaffected by the exception. `wait_for` actually *cancels* the task it was passed, if the timeout is reached, but this did not affect `long_task` because you shielded it from cancellation. Of course, if you *don't* catch the exception, but allow it to bubble up, that will interrupt the entire program (including the event loop).

You can actually test fairly easily, that you are dealing with the same task:

```py
from asyncio import create_task, run, shield, sleep, wait_for
from asyncio.exceptions import TimeoutError


async def wait(n: int) -> str:
    print("Starting to wait")
    for i in range(n):
        await sleep(1)
        print(f"Waited {i + 1} sec")
    print("Done waiting")
    return "foo"


async def main() -> None:
    long_task = create_task(wait(5))
    try:
        result = await wait_for(shield(long_task), timeout=1.5)
    except TimeoutError:
        print("Taking longer than usual. Please wait.")
        result = await long_task
    print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main())
```

Output:

```
Starting to wait
Waited 1 sec
Taking longer than usual. Please wait.
Waited 2 sec
Waited 3 sec
Waited 4 sec
Waited 5 sec
Done waiting
foo
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear and on-point reply. I think my reasoning was more or less correct. I am now a bit confused about task `long_task` in both `try` and `except` clauses. Since `long_task` is still running in `try` clause (even though exception was raised), is 'long_task' in `except` clause referring to same task from 'try' clause? Or is it being run afresh from line 'b'? I started learning asynchronous programming from few days back so may be I am asking a stupid question.

Comment: @mayankkaizen No worries. It is the same task. The same underlying `Future` on the event loop. See my extended answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your kind efforts. Now I understand things much better.